# Best practices for connecting jenkins from AWS US-east region to China Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, connectivity, amazon-vpc

One of the new requirement that I have is trying to use my Jenkins server which is set up in my AWS us-east account to deploy code to the application servers(in a private subnet) in the AWS china region. I'm worried about the security aspects while connecting to the China region from the US region.

What I have come up with is using an OpenVPN to connect to the china region and then go from there.

If anyone have a better solution please recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN (or a VPN in general) is the best option I know of in this scenario. Your connection is going to be going over the Internet so encrypting that connection with a VPN is the correct way to perform this task in a secure manner.